# How to update modules.conf for SELINUX in BUILDROOT?

Tags: buildroot, selinux

looking to disable some SELinux modules (set to off) and create others in modules.conf.  I don't see an obvious way of updating modules.conf as I tried adding my changes as a modules.conf patch but it failed given that the modules.conf file gets built and is not just downloaded by BR so it is not available for patching like other things under the refpolicy directory:

Build window output:

> refpolicy 2.20190609 PatchingApplying 0001-refpolicy-update-modules-conf.patch using patch:
> can't find file to patch at input line 3

I did see in the log that there is a support/sedoctool.py that autogenerates the policy/modules.conf file so that the file is NOT patchable like most other things in the ref policy.

The relevant section of the buildroot/output/build/refpolicy-2.20190609/Makefile:

```
# policy building support tools
support := support
genxml := $(PYTHON) $(support)/segenxml.py
gendoc := $(PYTHON) $(support)/sedoctool.py

<...snip...>

########################################
#
# Create config files
#
conf: $(mod_conf) $(booleans) generate$(booleans) $(mod_conf): conf.intermediate.INTERMEDIATE: conf.intermediate
conf.intermediate: $(polxml)
        @echo "Updating $(booleans) and $(mod_conf)"
        $(verbose) $(gendoc) -b $(booleans) -m $(mod_conf) -x $(polxml)
```

Part of the hsmlinux build.log showing the sedoctool.py (gendoc) being run:

> Updating policy/booleans.conf and policy/modules.conf
> .../build-buildroot-sawshark/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/python3 support/sedoctool.py -b policy/booleans.conf -m policy/modules.conf -x doc/policy.xml

I'm sure there is a standard way of doing this, just doesn't seem to be documented anywhere I can find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the sedoctool.py script is reading the doc/policy.xml. Looking at sedoctool.py:

```
#modules enabled and disabled values
MOD_BASE = "base"
MOD_ENABLED = "module"
MOD_DISABLED = "off"
```

<...snip...>

```
def gen_module_conf(doc, file_name, namevalue_list):
        """
        Generates the module configuration file using the XML provided and the
        previous module configuration.
        """
        # If file exists, preserve settings and modify if needed.
        # Otherwise, create it.
<...snip...>
                        mod_name = node.getAttribute("name")
                        mod_layer = node.parentNode.getAttribute("name")
<...snip...>
                        if mod_name and mod_layer:
                                file_name.write("# Layer: %s\n# Module: %s\n" % (mod_layer,mod_name))
                                if required:
                                        file_name.write("# Required in base\n")
                                file_name.write("#\n")

                               if [mod_name, MOD_DISABLED] in namevalue_list:
                                        file_name.write("%s = %s\n\n" % (mod_name, MOD_DISABLED))
                                # If the module is set as enabled.
                                elif [mod_name, MOD_ENABLED] in namevalue_list:
                                        file_name.write("%s = %s\n\n" % (mod_name, MOD_ENABLED))
                                # If the module is set as base.
                                elif [mod_name, MOD_BASE] in namevalue_list:
                                        file_name.write("%s = %s\n\n" % (mod_name, MOD_BASE))
```

So sedoctool.py has the nice feature of: "# If file exists, preserve settings and modify if needed." and modules.conf can just be added whole here via a complete file patch and the modules that are not desired set as "off" : refpolicy-2.20190609/policy/modules.conf and the script will update as needed based on desired policy.

One more detail is that in the next stage of the refpolicy Makefile (Building) the modules.conf with the updates is deleted in the beginning which kind of clashes with the ability of sedoctool to preserve the patched version of modules.conf...so patched the removal in the Building stage of the Makefile.

[7m>>> refpolicy 2.20190609 Building^[

<...snip...>

rm -f policy/modules.conf

The Makefile in refpolicy-2.20190609 has this line that I patched out because we are patching in our own modules.conf:

bare: clean
<...snip...>
$(verbose) rm -f $(mod_conf)

That patch looks like:

```
--- BUILDROOT/Makefile  2020-08-17 13:25:06.963804709 -0400
+++ FIX/Makefile  2020-08-17 19:25:29.540607763 -0400
@@ -636,7 +636,6 @@
        $(verbose) rm -f $(modxml)
        $(verbose) rm -f $(tunxml)
        $(verbose) rm -f $(boolxml)
-       $(verbose) rm -f $(mod_conf)
        $(verbose) rm -f $(booleans)
        $(verbose) rm -fR $(htmldir)
        $(verbose) rm -f $(tags)
```

BTW,
Creating a patch with a complete new file in pp1:q!:

```
diff -crB --new-file pp0 pp1 > pp0.patch
```